# Can't write a binary file

Tags: c++

I have the following piece of code in C++.

```
int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
ofstream output("Sample.txt", ios::out | ios::binary);

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
  output<<arr[i];
}
```

Now the Sample.txt is like this:

```
12345678910
```

Isn't the "Sample.txt" supposed to be in binary? Why doesn't it convert everything into binary when i opened the stream in binary mode. What should I do, incase i need binary of every element in the array and then print it to the file.

Comment: What do you mean by "in binary"?

Comment: binary values for corresponding integers in array, so if the integer in array is 5, it should print 101 instead of 5

Comment: Well, you need to use the `write` function to output raw data. But with that, it *does* print 101 (well, probably more like 0000000000000101) to disk, but whatever you're using to view the file isn't going to actually display the raw one's and zero's. Text-file viewers will try to decode it (with ASCII, for example), which is why when you open binary files in a text editor you see garbled crap. You never see 1's and 0's. Perhaps a hex-editor, which does do that, would be more suitable.

Comment: @GMan: Yes, i do understand that, i will see some garbled crap in text editor, but when i use write function, my program crashes . seem i m missing something very obvious.

Comment: If you actually want to see 1s and 0s, then you should be rather looking for a function to convert numbers to this representation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Isn't the "Sample.txt" supposed to be in binary?

No. What `std::ios::binary` does is to prevent things like the translation of `'\n'` from/to the platform-specific EOL. It will not skip the translation between the internal representation of the data bytes and their string translation. After all, that's what streams are all about. (Also, think of how you would stream an object of a user-defined type containing pointers in a binary representation.)

To actually write objects binary use `std::ostream::write()`. Beware, though, the result is platform-specific.

Comment: So how do i write the array as binary values into a file?

Comment: output.write((char*)arr, sizeof(arr));

Comment: if i say, output.write((char*)arr[i], sizeof(int)); the program crashed and output.write((char*)arr, sizeof(arr)) does not print anything in the Sample.txt file

Comment: @Jay: The correct solution is `output.write((char*)&arr[i], sizeof(int)))`

Answer (score 0):

Binary mode mostly means that (for example) there won't be a transformation between a new-line character that you program writes, and whatever your platform thinks marks the end of a line (e.g. "\r\n" on Windows, "\r" on the Ma).

To actually write binary, you'd typically use `ofstream.write()`.

Answer (score 0):

Binary just means that newline characters are not converted to/from the OS-specific format. Outputting a value of type `int` with `ofstream` will format it as decimal number (normal ASCII text).

For what you mean by binary, you should rather write values of type `char` or use the non-formatting function `output.write` ([docs here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ostream/write/)).

Answer (score 0):

Binary as in 'not text' means that no formatting is done like new lines and so on.

[See](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/):

> File streams opened in binary mode
>   perform input and output operations
>   independently of any format
>   considerations. Non-binary files are
>   known as text files, and some
>   translations may occur due to
>   formatting of some special characters
>   (like newline and carriage return
>   characters).

It will not translate for you to `0` and `1` format. Everything on pc is using `binary` format but when you open file and read it with editor, editor reads binary data and displays ASCII characters for you.